# removing and finding duplicate elements from an array

Tags: r

Given an array that can have duplicate elements, I would like to have two types of information derived from this array:

1) Are there any function that can return the derived array without any duplicated elements?

2) Are there any function that can list those duplicate elements?

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html

Comment: also, what would you like to be there in place of the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

#### Assuming `A` is your array:

```
dups <- duplicated(as.vector(A))
dim(dups) <- dim(A)
```

#### Question 2:

```
dups
```

#### Question 1:

```
# take a copy
ArrayWithNoDups <- A
ArrayWithNoDups[dups] <- NA
ArrayWithNoDups
```